# jQuery class selector is not working on elements generated by JSON in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I am having a problem and perhaps the I'm the one who is committing the error or did not understand how the DOM works at all, I'm not sure. The point is that the project I'm working from the server side using PHP and with this piece of code:

```
$user[] = '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="' . $this->generateUrl('edit-user', array('id' => $entity->getId()), true) . '"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Editar</a> <a class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete" data-id="' . $entity->getId() . '" href ="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Eliminar</a>';
```

This convert to JSON and then using this call:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
    "ajax": Routing.generate('get-list-user'),
    "language": {
        "url": "{{ asset('bundles/backend/js/plugin/datatables/resources/dataTables.spanish.lang.json') }}"
    }
});
```

It relies on a Datatable component. That generate a HTML code like this:

```
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="http://tanane.dev/app_dev.php/admin/user/1/edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Editar</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete" data-id="1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Eliminar</a>
</td>
```

Then on the same template where I am rendereando element after having loaded jQuery and all the necessary libraries I'm using this code:

```
$(".confirm-delete").on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

when you click any button with `.confirm-delete` generated by PHP and rendered in the template but the same is not working for me in the console nothing comes out. Am I doing something wrong? It is a normal behavior of the DOM? I had understood that I could use `.on ()` to create elements in the air and if I remember what I used but in this case not working for me, any ideas or help?

Comment: You should use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). `$("#datatable").on('click', ".confirm-delete", function () {});`

Comment: @Ninsly ohhh you're a genius, that's the problem now I learn something new. Please post a answer to give you the points and accept your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the following function:

```
$(".confirm-delete").on('click', function () { 
    //Code 
});
```

Only the current existing DOM elements that match `.confirm-delete` will be attached the event. If you need to attach events dyanmically, you should use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Event delegation will attach the event to the parent element, but only fire the event if the 2nd selector matches one of the clicked elements:

```
$("#datatable").on('click', ".confirm-delete", function () { 
    //Code 
});
```

With that code, every time `#datatable` is clicked, it will check if one of the clicked elements is `.confirm-delete` and if so, it will execute the code.

Sidenote: `this` inside the function still refers to the `.confirm-delete` element